# How to vertically align a image to the floated text

Tags: html, css

I am developing a two column responsive layout. Where one column has an image and the other do have the text. I want to align to the image `vertical:middle;` where I tried several techinques and stackoverflow answer till i could able to achieve it. Here is my code follows

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
         <h2>Quicker answers to your customer’s questions.</h2>
         <p>Potential customers visit your site to learn more about what you do and how it can help them. When they have a question, our web chat tool gives them a direct line to your customer support and expert knowled</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**STYLE**

```
h2{
    margin:0;
}
.col{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/y208tfc0/)**

Can any one help to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 For placing a kitten there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `display: inline-block;`

```
h2 {
    margin:0;
}

.col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.row {
    font-size: 0; // remove space between inline-block elements
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/y208tfc0/1/

Comment: To some issue when i give `inline-block` and `width: 50%` my content in breaking down to next line.

Comment: So you wanna use inline-block ?

Comment: S i avoided the `inline-block` just to avoid breaking into new lines on `50%` of width. And you made the point really clear. :)

Comment: @Benjamin you could also use other techniques to avoid breaking into 2 lines like `letter-spacing: -0.31em` or comment at markup. check this out http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

You could display the row as table and col as table-cell?

css;

```
    .row {
       display: table;
    }
    .col {
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to use `display: inline-block;` property.**

Live demo there : http://jsfiddle.net/y208tfc0/5/

```
h2{
    margin:0;
}
.row {
    display: inline-block;
}
.col{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 45%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

*Instead of putting `.row {font-size: 0 }` and breaking font-size rules, I choose to put .row display: inline-block.*

Comment: I dont wanna use inline-block i just need to happened using float thats the challenge im facing

Comment: If you absolutely need to use floats, then tell it when you ask for help ?

Comment: `inline-block` with `width:50%` breaking my content down to next line

Comment: Something in fiddle adds padding or margin. WIth a proper reset CSS, it won't.

Comment: No, it's just white space of HTML elements, check there : http://jsfiddle.net/y208tfc0/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
h2{
    margin:0;
}
.col{
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;/*Add display table-cell*/
}

.row{
    display: table;/*Add display table*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y208tfc0/4/)

Comment: Will this one compatible with responsive design

Comment: @Benjamin yes you don't have problem.

Comment: This isn't reason for downvote imo. I didn't even see your answer before i post mine.

Comment: Im not saying what they did is right, im just suggesting that may be the reason as you lost a vote and i gained one. I could be wrong of course. sorry.